# Docker reloading certificate

Tags: docker, certificate, registry, daemon, docker-registry

I'm planning to move my registry to another server, where I will also want to use a new certificate, which is placed in /etc/docker/certs.d/myregistry/

I need to deploy the certificate on all servers, but I don't really want to restart the docker daemon, to "load" the new certificate file. Is there a way to reload the certificate file, without restarting all containers?

Will the command "kill -HUP " help me on this and reload the certificate file?
When I just replace the certificate file, it doesn't seem to work as expected.

I'm using Docker version 1.10.3

If there is no way, without restarting the docker daemon, would it be possible with docker version 13, which supports live restore, when restarting the docker daemon? - Means I could restart the daemon, to reload the certificate, without restarting the containers.

Thank you!

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#configuration-reloading) for `SIGHUP` on `dockerd` doesn't list anything about the TLS certificates unfortunately.